# how to detect blinking in face api.js I have the following code

Tags: reactjs, face-detection, face-api

I made a blink application using face api js but it can't be what should it be?,I made a blink application using face api js but it can't be what should it be?,I made a blink application using face api js but it can't be what should it be?